# Use layout host application for engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I am developing an engine for a Rails application and have some problem when I try to render view from my engine with layout from host application.
Layout have a form for search and resource routes which link to host application but when I render view from engine all link will get prefix from engine.
What approach to use layout from host application when it's have link and to host resources and to engine resources.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to inherit from the main app's `ApplicationController`:

```
# engine/app/controllers/engine/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   # inherited layout
end
```

If you've got [`isolate_namespace`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#class-Rails::Engine-label-Isolated+Engine) in your engine, you'll still be able to inherit from `ApplicationController`, but may have to use `main_app.layout` to call the layout from the "main" application.

[We've done this type of thing before](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler/blob/master/app/controllers/exception_handler/exception_controller.rb#L2).